# What are the real world uses of Eigenbasis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

The title pretty much says it all, I am wondering what the real world application (especially pertaining to electrical engineering) of an Eigenbasis is. I am also having some trouble understanding exactly what the Eigenbasis is so a little help on that front would be great. Any and all insight would be great! Thanks!

Comment: See for instance, quantum mechanics.